# C# Inheriting polymorphic types

Tags: c#, inheritance

Starting out with a basic class called Weapon, I intended it to be polymorphic as follows:

```
public class Weapon
{
    // Some code..
}

public class MachineGun : Weapon
{
    // Extend the base code..
}
```

These classes define the basic functionality, however they do not contain any code to draw the weapon. This drawing only needs to be added in the Client application, the Server simply uses the MachineGun class without needing visualization.

```
public class DrawableWeapon : Weapon
{
    // Adding draw calls and properties
}

public class DrawableMachineGun : DrawableWeapon
{
    // The problem:
    // You have no access to the properties of the original MachineGun here
}
// or..
public class DrawableMachineGun : MachineGun
{
    // Same problem, only now you miss properties of the DrawableWeapon
}
```

The problem is losing either functionality of the MachineGun() class or the DrawableWeapon() class, since C# has no multiple inheritance.

Defining the Weapon class as an interface gave no succes either, you can't define methods in an interface which is exactly what I need to reduce code.

The only (partial) solution I found was for methods: define them in a seperate static class and on each method call in a drawable class, call this static method as well. This still leaves out all properties, and leads to long method calls..

What is the best option to implement this nicely? Is there a better programming pattern to use in this case?

Comment: I think you have to make a base class Drawable and make it baseclass of Weapon. So you have Drawable in MaschineGun

Comment: What do you mean by _draw_? Unholster or render to screen? If you ask me, the action of unholstering a weapon is performed by the carrier of the weapon, not the weapon itself. In that case, you don't need multiple inheritance.

Comment: By drawing I ment to visualize the weapon on screen in the Client side version. I edited the post to make this more clear.

Comment: you should add a little more detail (a couple of examples of methods/fields you would like to have in Drawable, and MachineGun). Depending on how complex your scenario is you may be able to reduce some code duplication by working with interfaces + extension methods but there are cases when that is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern:

```
    public class Weapon
    {
       public virtual void Shot()
       { 
          // Some code...
       }
    }

    public class MachineGun : Weapon
    {
       public override void Shot()
       { 
          // Extend base code...
       }
    }

    public class DrawableWeapon : Weapon
    {
       Weapon mWeapon;

       public override void Shot()
       { 
          mWeapon.Shot();
       }

        // Adding draw calls and properties
    }
```

Comment: I think you should use generics to implement the drawableweapon class since if machine gun override shot you cannot call the override from drawableweapon

Comment: Thanks! By overriding some of the properties I was able to get the desired effect. And as answer to the above comment, the mWeapon.Shot() calls the override function of MachineGun before calling the base function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorator pattern to **extend your classes without inheritance**. It is good to remember [favor object composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle for this kind of polymorphism problems.

```
interface Weapon : Weapon {
    void Fire();
}

class MachineGun : Weapon {
    public override void Fire() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

class HandGun : Weapon {
    public override void Fire() {
        // Do something
    }
}

abstract class WeaponDecorator : Weapon {
    protected Weapon weapon;

    public WeaponDecorator(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    // Implement methods by calling this.weapon's method

    public virtual void Fire() {
        weapon.Fire();
    }
}

class DrawableWeapon : WeaponDecorator {

    public DrawableWeapon (Weapon weapon) : base(weapon) {

    }

    public override void Fire() {
        PlayShakingEffect();
        base.Fire();
    }

    private void PlayShakingEffect() {

    }
}
```

Having this code we can make any type of `Weapon` drawable. Note all weapons are still instance of `Weapon`.

```
Weapon machineGun = new MachineGun();
Weapon handGun = new HandGun();

Weapon drawableMachineGun = new DrawableWeapon(new MachineGun());
Weapon drawableHandGun = new DrawableWeapon(new HandGun());
```

Comment: How does this help with accessing properties of `MachineGun`? (for example)

Comment: Decorator can expose its weapon instance by a getter and you can use that instance after casting. If you are about to use `MachineGun` specific methods, I assume you are sure that you have a `MachineGun` instance or your decorator object has it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different way of looking at this is to create a composition of different classes rather than use classic OO inheritence. This emphasises the use of interfaces rather than class hierarchies where general purpose code is not inherited but consumed. Example;

```
interface IDrawer 
{
    void Draw();
}
class WeaponDrawer : IDrawer // class carries out the drawing of a weapon

class Weapon : IDrawer
{
    private IDrawer : weaponDrawer = new WeaponDrawer();
    // Delegate the draw method to a completely different class.
    public void Draw()
    {
        this.weaponDrawer.Draw();
    }
}
```

This follows the SOLID principles by keeping the definition of Weapon seperate from the function of drawing the weapon. (You could of course use an IOC container instead of the "= new WeaponDrawer()"). You end up with a set of single purpose classes instead of a complex inheritence hierarchy - it looks like more code, but you might well find that the design is clearer and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using method injection to allow multiple drawer implementations, while you can add IDrawable where needed.

```
    interface IDrawable {
       Draw(WeaponDrawer)
    }

    class DrawableWeapon : Weapon, IDrawable {
      Draw(WeaponDrawer wd){
        wd.Draw(this);
     }
    }

    class WeaponDrawer {
       Draw(Weapon weapon){
          //drawing logic here
       }
    }
```

Comment: And how does `WeaponDrawer` access the different properties of both `DrawableWeapon` and `MachineGun`?

Comment: there would we no DrawableWeapon (from original example) as this would be implemented by WeaponDrawer

Comment: You have `DrawableWeapon` in your code... Anyway, OK so `WeaponDrawer` has the common drawing properties, etc. How does it access weapon specific properties, such as `MachineGun` properties? Which I am sure is what the question is asking

Comment: I understand, that all classes inherit from weapon and some add drawing functionality and some don't. Second, the drawing functionality should be at one place to reduce code. This is to achieve single line of inheritance. The WeaponDrawer.Draw could be invoked with Weapon as an argument to access Weapon properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics and the decorator pattern to implement the DrawableWeapon

```
public class DrawableWeapon<T> : Weapon where T : Weapon
{
     T _weapon;

     public void Shot()
     {
        _weapon.Shot();
     }
}
```

In this way you get a distinct DrawableWeapon class for each weapon you implement.